# Android Wear Remote Voice Input to Main Action Intent

Tags: android, input, voice, wear-os

I'm playing around with Android Wear according to the documentation that Google provided (http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/remote-input.html) but I stuck in a part where I'm probably missing something. Can you guys help out? Here's the code.

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class);
        viewIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.extraStringTag), extraString);

PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + Uri.encode(location));
mapIntent.setData(geoUri);
PendingIntent mapPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mapIntent, 0);

BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigStyle.bigText(eventDescription);

String[] replyChoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.reply_choices);
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(getString(R.string.extraStringTag))
        .setLabel(replyTitle)
        .setChoices(replyChoices)
        .build();

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.questionblock)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.mariopagebg))
        .setStyle(bigStyle)
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventDescription)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.mariomap,
                mapString, mapPendingIntent);

Notification notification = new WearableNotifications.Builder(notificationBuilder)
        .addRemoteInputForContentIntent(remoteInput)
        .build();

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

As declared in the documentation, my primary action button does not get converted into "Reply" as it should be.

Comment: Just to clarify things, My code might contain additional code blocks, I tried the exact code in the documentation as well, and no luck.

Comment: What is the value for replyTitle in your code?

Comment: It was a dummy string, "Reply Title"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with adding the activity to my manifest. A honest mistake. For those who are playing with android wear, keep in mind that pending activities in your code block which you did not add to your manifest won't crash your application. There won't be a 'missing class declaration' in your stack trace.